# In Spring MVC, I have a @ModelAttribute and it is throwing an exception. If i get this exception, I want to display a page. How?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Ya, basically the question.  In a few of my handlers I have a @ModelAttribute, in an extreme edge case that @ModelAttribute can throw an excetion.  When that happens I want to display an error page.  I want to do this all in the @ModelAttribute method as I want to avoid redundant code in the different request handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried @ExceptionHandler?

```
@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(YourException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Handle it
    return yourView;
}
```

Comment: no problem - most of the annotations that work on a RequestMapping should work on an ExceptionHandler too...

Comment: Note: the @ ExceptionHandler only applies to the methods of the class in which it appears. If you have multiple classes, you will need to supply an @ ExceptionHandler in each class.